# Как преобразовать true в 1 false в 0?

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('input[name=spravkaDox]').is(':checked')
```

Мне это выражение вернет `true` если `checkbox` отмечен. Как мне это преобразовать в 1 если `true` и в 0 если `false`?

```
if($('input[name=spravkaDox]').is(':checked'))
{ 
    return 1;
} else {
        return 0;
}
```

Не верно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[name=spravkaDox]').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0
```

или

```
$('input[name=spravkaDox]').is(':checked') && 1 || 0;
```

Comment: Или 
  
    $('input[name=spravkaDox]').is(':checked')*1

=)